# Cannot create a cloud function in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the GUI to save/deploy a cloud function but I get and error when I try to save it.  I can't deploy the default "hello world" function that gets pre-populated.  The error says:
   An unknown error has occurred in Cloud Functions: "undefined"

I have functions that were previously updated in July 2018 that are not running and I'm trying to fix them.  But without being able to save any edits I can't tell what's broken.

This is only an issue with one of my projects.  I can deploy functions in other projects and I can delete functions in the problem project.

Where should I start to look for the cause of the error?

Comment: Close your browser and all browser windows. Restart your browser. I have seen this happen once in a while when my machine gets low on memory (too many windows open).

Comment: That was unsuccessful. :-(  I still can't create a function.

Answer (score 1):

My function didn't have a default service account (not sure how that got lost).  In the advanced section of the cloud functions GUI I selected my default service account and I can now save functions.